# Efficient way of skipping a line in a stream

Tags: java, stream, bufferedreader

I have a list of files and for each of the file i have the following code in JAVA to skip a line from the second file. The files may be are 4KB or max less than 8KB. This approach is working. Is there any efficient way to skip the first line. I am getting the header of only the first file in the list.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                        if (addHeader) {
                            addHeader = false;
                        }
                        else {
                            reader.readLine();
                        }
                        ByteStreams.copy(new ReaderInputStream(reader), outputStream);
```

This has been working well so far. I want to know if this is the best approach.

Comment: `Files.lines(YourPath).skip(1)`?

Comment: When `addHeader` is `true`, you can skip the overhead of charset decoding and encoding and just copy `inputStream` to `outputStream`…